# jQuery/Cheerio: How to recursively get certain elements by name/tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I'm trying to make a bot that scrapes links from a website. I am running in to some weird error that I cannot figure out. My guess is that the second `if` statement is failing to check and also my unfamiliarity with jQuery is not helping.

Error:

> element.each is not a function

```js
const $ = load(html);
const html = $("#id");

const temp = [];

function recursive(element) {
  if (element.name === "a") {
    temp.push(element);
  }
  
  if (!element || element.children().length > 0 === false) {
    return "DID NOT FIND IT OR NO CHILDREN FOUND";
  }

  return element.each((_, item) => recursive(item));
}

recursive(html);
return temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to create simple snippet demonstrating what you seem to accomplished with JQuery.

Firstly, your check if for the Tag of an element doesn't seemed to be working properly. I had to use the `.prop('tagName')` to get the Tag of the element. And it gets returned in all capital letters.

Your second IF-Statement should work fine, but the `.each()` Method didnt work as expected. You want to iterate through all children and start the recursive function. And the way you provided the child element didnt end up working.
The `.each()` Method want a callback function which provides two parameters as you have uses correctly. but the Item is a normal HTML Node and you had to select it with the JQuery Constant `$` like `$(item)`. This gives you the desired JQuery Element you can work with.

```js
const html = $("#test");

const temp = [];

function recursive(element) {
  if (element.prop("tagName") === "A") {
    temp.push(element);
  }
  if (!element || element.children().length > 0 === false) {
    return "DID NOT FIND IT OR NO CHILDREN FOUND";
  }

  return element.children().each((i, item) => recursive($(item)));
}

recursive(html);
console.log(temp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div class="headings">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <a href="./main.html">Main Page</a>
  </div>
  <div class="test-cls">
    <button>Hello</button>
    <a href="./test.html">Test Page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just figured it out, damn...

Comment: was confusing each() function with forEach() method